# How to conditionally remove X-Frame-Options from reverse proxy response in IIS?

Tags: iis

I have IIS 10 in front of a reverse proxy.

The reverse proxy sends responses with the header X-Frame-Options.

I need to remove this header from the response when another header is set to something:

```
Condition : CustomHeader is set to CustomValue
```

I have tried the following code (that doesn't include the condition because I don't know how to do it) but it doesn't work. The response still includes X-Frame-Options header.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below setting:

```
<httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
      <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
   </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

More information you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/#attributes.